# WCF Application - need "app start" code for both http and tcp bindings

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF application that requires some app initialization code to fire when the app starts. Currently the code sits in my Application_Start method in global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Whatever..
}
```

However, my WCF app has both http (asp.net) and TCP (netTcpBinding) endpoints, depending on what service is being called. This code will only fire for normal http endpoints, not TCP. I need the app start code to fire regardless of whether a client call was made via tcp or http. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Application_Start` is only for HTTP pipeline. If you need protocol agnostic initialization [use AppInitialize method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/11/511514.aspx).

Comment: Yup, that's basically it. Remember to set the build action of that file you add to app_code to "content", and it works