# Windsor IOC in a non-Http WCF application - error initialising IOC kernel

Tags: wcf, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, was

I have a problem trying to initialise my IOC container in a WCF application. The application is non HTTP based using WAS.

When I start the application I get this error message...

`Kernel was null, did you forgot to call DefaultServiceHostFactory.RegisterContainer`

I have seen other answers to this solution which say to do the following...

- Add a Factory definition to the ServiceHost definition e.g.

`Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration"`

- Create a class in th App_Code folder with a static method called AppInitialize(). This method should then automatically be called and you can use it to register your container.

I have done this but my AppInitialize method is not called and I am still getting the error above.

Thanks.

Comment: So how exactly does your code/config look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Windsor Container Registration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926140/wcf-windsor-container-registration)

Comment: happy to help but there is definitely not enough code here to work with, if you can provide some snips i think i can help

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2455039/126014

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2042858/126014